# React Typescript - Webpack externals module can not find

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I created a react application using create-react-app with typescript template and run the eject command too.

I just need to get configuration from external json file and read it from components file, anywhere in the application.
So I did following change to use webpack config json

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

**webpack.configjson**
 // Load external configuration files

```
 externals: {
      'Configurator': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? require('./config.prod.json') : require('./config.dev.json'))
    }
```

[image]

**Ts file**

```
import Configurator from 'Configurator';
```

But it gives following error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line and make sure your config.*.js files are exporting modules:

```
externals: {
  'Configurator': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV) === 'production' ? path.resolve(__dirname, 'config.prod.js') : path.resolve(__dirname, 'config.dev.js')
}
```

Try adding the following to your tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

You can also try to use a non-relative path for your import since this will reduce the complexity of your webpack and tsconfig, then you can drop the webpack external config and do something like.

in **webpack.config**

```
...
plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
})],
...
```

Then import like so:

```
const config = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? require('../config.prod.js') : require('../config.dev.js')
```

Comment: Still `Cannot find module 'Configurator'.` issue is giving

Comment: Perhaps you need to change the json files to js files that export modules?

Comment: @JanithWidarshana Is there any reason why you are not using a relative import for your config? i.e import Configurator from '../config.dev.js' I think the issue lies in your tsconfig since typscript does not know where to find the module, it looks for non-relative imports in node_modules

Comment: I added my tsconfig.json file to question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205649/discussion-between-janith-widarshana-and-deowk).